# Error al insertar registros en dos tablas diferentes desde un mismo modelo

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero insertar registros en 2 tablas diferentes desde un mismo modelo. Cuando le doy guardar me marca:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'conexion.php';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (id_rol, nombre, apellidoP,apellidoM, correo, pass, campus) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('issssss', $obj->id_rol, $obj->nombre, $obj->apellidoP, $obj->apellidoM, $obj->correo, $obj->pass,$obj->campus);

$stmt->execute();

$idGenerado = $stmt->insert_id;


if($obj->id_rol==3){

 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id_actividad FROM actividad");

 $stmt->bind_result($id_actividad);

 $stmt->execute();


while ($stmt->fetch()) {

  echo $id_actividad." ".$idGenerado."\n";

  $evaluador = 27;

  $puntuacion1=0;

  $puntuacion2=0;

  $observacion ="0";

 $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO puntuacion ( id_actividad, id_usuario_docente, id_usuario_evaluador, puntuacion_obtenida, puntuacion_evaluada, observacion, fecha) 
VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,now())");

 $stmt2->bind_param('siiiiss', $id_actividad, $idGenerado, $evaluador, $puntuacion1, $puntuacion2, $observacion);

  $stmt2->execute();


  $stmt2->close();
 }

 $stmt->close();
} 
echo "registro almacenado"

? >
```

Comment: Buenos días, te recomiendo que leas [ask], y después rehagas tu pregunta

Comment: `$stmt2->bind_param('siiiiss'` envías  7 parámetros y pasas solo 6 valores. puede ser un detalle. además debe verificar los nombres de las columnas o de las tablas que emplea , quizá hay algo incorrecto ahi

Comment: es que el parametro 7 es la fecha, no la pongo por que en el values pongo now();

Comment: En pocas palabras el numero de parámetros debe ser igual a la cantidad de  ? en su prepare

Comment: Hice esa inserción  sola y no me marco error pero cuando quiero hacerla junto con la otra inserción es donde me genera el error

Comment: Hola Uriel, tu código no gestiona los errores de manera correcta y, además, no haces uso en ningún momento de `$stmt->store_result()` tras `$stmt->execute()`, por lo que provocarás resultados extraños en consultas anidadas. Redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Descripción del problema

El mensaje de error que estás recibiendo es debido a que no estás gestionando correctamente los errores que se puedan producir durante las consultas SQL.

> Call to a member function `bind_param()` on **boolean**

Te está indicando que en la línea `$stmt2->bind_param()` la variable `$stmt2` contiene un dato booleano y no un recurso mysqli con una consulta SQL.

Eso es debido a que la llamada a [`$db->prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) falló:

> **Valores devueltos:** `mysqli_prepare()` devuelve un objeto de sentencia o **`FALSE`** si ocurre un error.

### Gestionando los errores

Para ver los mensajes de error que se producen debes cambiar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("
  INSERT INTO puntuacion (
    id_actividad,
    id_usuario_docente,
    id_usuario_evaluador,
    puntuacion_obtenida,
    puntuacion_evaluada,
    observacion,
    fecha
  ) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    now()
  )
");
/* Si falló la consulta mostramos el mensaje de error */
if ($stmt2 === false) {
  die($db->error);
}
```

Lo mismo hay que hacer tras el [`$stmt2->execute()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.execute) (también devuelve `false` en caso de error):

```
if ($stmt2->execute() === false) {
  die($stmt2->error);
}
```

Eso debes hacerlo tanto con `$stmtp` como con `$stmtp2`.

### Raíz del problema

Además, cuando vas a realizar consultas anidadas debes descargar el buffer de la consulta anterior mediante `$stmt->store_result()`:

```
/* Primero ejecutamos la consulta (verificando si falló) */
$stmt->execute();
/* Después almacenamos el resultado */
$stmt->store_result();
/* Por último asociamos los campos con variables para el fetch() */
$stmt->bind_result($id_actividad);
/* Ahora podemos trabajar con los resultados */
while ($stmt->fetch()) { ... }
```

El orden es importante y existe una nota en la documentación de [`$mysqli::bind_result()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-result) que lo indica así:

> **Nota:** Observe que todas las columnas **deben ser vinculadas después de llamar a `mysqli_stmt_execute()` y antes de llamar a `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`**.

Quedando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'conexion.php';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$stmt = $db->prepare("
  INSERT INTO usuario (
    id_rol,
    nombre,
    apellidoP,
    apellidoM,
    correo,
    pass,
    campus
  ) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
  )"
);
/* Si falló la consulta mostramos el mensaje de error */
if ($stmt === false) {
    die($db->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param('issssss',
  $obj->id_rol,
  $obj->nombre,
  $obj->apellidoP,
  $obj->apellidoM,
  $obj->correo,
  $obj->pass,
  $obj->campus
);

if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    die($stmt->error);
}
/* Obtenemos el id de la inserción */
$idGenerado = $stmt->insert_id;
/* Ya no necesitamos de nuevo la consulta preparada */
$stmt->close();

if($obj->id_rol == 3) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id_actividad FROM actividad");
    /* Si falló la consulta mostramos el mensaje de error */
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die($db->error);
    }
    if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
        die($stmt->error);
    }
    /* Descargamos los datos para poder hacer consultas anidadas */
    $stmt->store_result();
    /* Asignamos a $id_actividad el campo por cada fetch() */
    $stmt->bind_result($id_actividad);
    /* Iteramos los resultados */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $id_actividad, " ", $idGenerado, PHP_EOL;
        $evaluador = 27;
        $puntuacion1 = 0;
        $puntuacion2 = 0;
        $observacion = "0";
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("
          INSERT INTO puntuacion (
            id_actividad,
            id_usuario_docente,
            id_usuario_evaluador,
            puntuacion_obtenida,
            puntuacion_evaluada,
            observacion,
            fecha
          ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            now()
          )
        ");
        /* Si falló la consulta mostramos el mensaje de error */
        if ($stmt2 === false) {
            die($db->error);
        }
        $stmt2->bind_param('siiiis',
          $id_actividad,
          $idGenerado,
          $evaluador,
          $puntuacion1,
          $puntuacion2,
          $observacion
        );
        if ($stmt2->execute() === false) {
            die($stmt2->error);
        }
        $stmt2->close();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
echo "registro almacenado";
```

Comment: hola oscar lo hice asi como me pusiste en el ejemplo pero me marca este error          mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables                                No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Comment: Disculpa, aún estaba editando (en un editor por separado, aquí no es buen sitio para hacerlo). Estoy editando la respuesta.

Comment: Hecho. En `siiiis` sobraba la última `s`. Prueba ahora. Por cierto, la primera `s` creo que se podría sustituir por una `i`.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo hice y si salio, la primera **s** la puse asi por que es varchar, por que las actividades  la pongo manual un ejemplo(1.2) o (1.2.3) y si la pongo **i** me marca error por que solo acepta valores enteros, por esos decidi ponerla varchar.                                                                muchas gracias de nuevo por la ayuda oscar saludos

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda. He agregado más información y enlaces para que puedan ser de ayuda a otro usuarios que busquen este mismo problema en internet. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta haciendo uso de la marca **✓** que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta.